# Drools conflict resolver with salience problem

Tags: drools, rule

I've found strange behavior of drools engine. 
I have two rules with different saliences. As described in drools documentation

> 3.3.4.1. Conflict Resolution
>
> Conflict resolution is required when
>   there are multiple rules on the
>   agenda. (The basics to this are
>   covered in chapter "Quick Start".) As
>   firing a rule may have side effects on
>   the working memory, the rule engine
>   needs to know in what order the rules
>   should fire (for instance, firing
>   ruleA may cause ruleB to be removed
>   from the agenda).
>
> The default conflict resolution
>   strategies employed by Drools are:
>   Salience and LIFO (last in, first
>   out).
>
> The most visible one is salience (or
>   priority), in which case a user can
>   specify that a certain rule has a
>   higher priority (by giving it a higher
>   number) than other rules. In that
>   case, the rule with higher salience
>   will be preferred. LIFO priorities are
>   based on the assigned Working Memory
>   Action counter value, with all rules
>   created during the same action
>   receiving the same value. The
>   execution order of a set of firings
>   with the same priority value is
>   arbitrary.

But executing my two rules with 5 objects for each type gives strange results - On some objects, rule with salience 1 is executed earlier than rule with salience 10.
If I remove update from rule, first rules with salience 10 are executed, and only then with salience 1.

```
 package com.sample

import com.sample.DroolsTest.Message;
import com.sample.DroolsTest.Message2;



rule "Hello World2"
    salience 10
    when
        m : Message()
        m2 : Message2(status <0)
    then

        System.out.println( "Second Rule With Salience 10"); 
        System.out.println( "m status = "+m.getStatus()); 
        System.out.println( "m2 status = "+m2.getStatus()); 
        m2.setStatus(m2.getStatus()*(-1));
        update(m2);
end

rule "Hello World3"
    salience 1
    when
        m2 : Message2()
        m : Message()
    then
        System.out.println( "Third Rule With Salience 1"); 
        System.out.println( "m status = "+m.getStatus()); 
        System.out.println( "m2 status = "+m2.getStatus()); 
end

rule "GoodBye"
    salience 0
    when
        eval(true)
    then
        System.out.println( "End" );
end
```

And here is the java code to make you test it faster

```
    package com.sample;

    import org.drools.KnowledgeBase;
    import org.drools.KnowledgeBaseFactory;
    import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilder;
    import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderError;
    import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderErrors;
    import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory;
    import org.drools.builder.ResourceType;
    import org.drools.io.ResourceFactory;
    import org.drools.logger.KnowledgeRuntimeLogger;
    import org.drools.logger.KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory;
    import org.drools.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession;

    /**
     * This is a sample class to launch a rule.
     */
    public class DroolsTest {

        public static final void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                // load up the knowledge base
                KnowledgeBase kbase = readKnowledgeBase();
                StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
                KnowledgeRuntimeLogger logger = KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newFileLogger(ksession, "test");
                // go !
                System.out.println("Start");
                for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                    Message message = new Message(i);
                    ksession.insert(message);
                    Message2 message2 = new Message2(-i);
                    ksession.insert(message2);
                }
                ksession.fireAllRules();
                logger.close();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private static KnowledgeBase readKnowledgeBase() throws Exception {
            KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
            kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("Sample.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);
            KnowledgeBuilderErrors errors = kbuilder.getErrors();
            if (errors.size() > 0) {
                for (KnowledgeBuilderError error: errors) {
                    System.err.println(error);
                }
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse knowledge.");
            }
            KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
            kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
            return kbase;
        }

        public static class Message {

            private int status;

            public int getStatus() {
                return this.status;
            }

            public Message(int status) {
                super();
                this.status = status;
            }

            public void setStatus(int status) {
                this.status = status;
            }

        }

    public static class Message2 {

            private int status;

            public Message2(int status) {
                this.status = status;
            }

            public int getStatus() {
                return this.status;
            }

            public void setStatus(int status) {
                this.status = status;
            }

        }

}
```

Thanks, I really appreciate your help.
PS: I know, that rely on the sequence of rule firing is not a great idea, but salience seemed to me trustworthy, before I ran on this one.

Comment: If you change the insert order it will execute first the rule with salience 10.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with drools and the salience as sakharuta.

@titu: I took the example above and changed the insert order. Now the salience works right BUT why? I thought the salience has the most priority and is the first conflict resolution strategy and then afterwards LIFO.
In my complex use case I have to insert up to 200.000 objects to the working memory and I have no influence on the inserted order so I only can rely on the salience...

I also really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

looking at your drl file, your are giving condition "when" part  m2 : Message2(status <0)
,Remember that LHS is only evaluated at assert time or when a modify()/update() on a given fact is called.  So, at assert time, condition will evaluate to true and activate the rule. You never call modify()/update on the same object.Message2, and so,your condition is never re-evaluated. That is why you will get strange behavior.
That is the reason why u will be getting desired behavior without update.